# Why too many values showed on page?

Tags: angular

I have a code like this to show some values on a page.

**In main component :**

```
<app-budget-item-list></app-budget-item-list>
```

**In the `BudgetItemList`**

```
<div class="income-column">
        <h1>GELİRLER</h1>
        <div class="budget-items" *ngFor="let item of budgetitems">
            <div >
                <app-budget-item-card *ngIf="item.amount>0" [isIncome]="true" ></app-budget-item-card>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="expense-column" >
        <h1>GİDERLER</h1>
        <div class="budget-items" *ngFor="let item of budgetitems">
            <div >
                <app-budget-item-card *ngIf="item.amount<0" [isIncome]="false"></app-budget-item-card>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

**In the `BudgetItemCard` Component**

```
<div class="root" *ngFor="let item of budgetitems">
<div class="budget-item" [ngClass]="{ 'income' : isIncome, expense : !isIncome }" >
    <div class="description" >
        <p>{{item.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="amount">
        <p>{{item.amount}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also `ts` files are like this :

**Main :**

```
 budgetitems : BudgetItem[] = new Array<BudgetItem>();
 returnItems(){
 return this.budgetitems;
 }
```

**BudgetItemList :**

```
budgetitems : BudgetItem[];
constructor(private model : MainComponentComponent){ 
this.budgetitems = model.returnItems();
}
```

**BudgetItemCard :**

```
 @Input() isIncome : boolean = false;
 budgetitems : BudgetItem[]

 constructor(private model : MainComponentComponent) {
 this.budgetitems= this.model.returnItems();
 }
```

If I add an element result is like that :
[First element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWWrY.png)

But if I add a second element result is :
[Second element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHNje.png)

Could anyone let me know which is my mistake ?

Comment: why are you looping twice over budgetitems, both in BudgetItemList and in BudgetItemCard?

Comment: To check the value of the amount in budgetitemlist  if greater than zero dont' show on the expensecolumn etc. In budgetitemcard To add the income or expense class of the entered value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each column `GELİRLER` and `GİDERLER`, you loop over your `budgetitems` array in order to only display the items that fits (according to the amount) the *ngIf condition in each `BudgetItemCard` component.

But as you loop over the `budgetitems` array inside your `BudgetItemCard` component, it then displays the items without any condition.

So for example for the `GELİRLER` colunm with `budgetitems` having a first item with positive amount and a second item with negative amount :

- the first item (with positive amount) will pass the condition
- the second item (with negative amount) won't pass the condition

But as you loop again over `budgetitems` inside the `BudgetItemCard` component, it'll display the two items as there is no condition inside this component.

To avoid it, you should just pass the item passing the condition to the `BudgetItemCard` component by adding a `item` attritube on the  `app-budget-item-card` tag:

```html
<div class="income-column">
        <h1>GELİRLER</h1>
        <div class="budget-items" *ngFor="let item of budgetitems">
            <div >
                <app-budget-item-card *ngIf="item.amount>0" [isIncome]="true" ></app-budget-item-card>
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="expense-column" >
        <h1>GİDERLER</h1>
        <div class="budget-items" *ngFor="let item of budgetitems">
            <div >
                <app-budget-item-card [item]="item" *ngIf="item.amount<0" [isIncome]="false"></app-budget-item-card>
                
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then use `@Input() item` to get its value inside the `BudgetItemCard` component (without looping over bugdetitems) :

```js
@Input() item
```

```html
<div class="budget-item" [ngClass]="{ 'income' : isIncome, expense : !isIncome }" >
    <div class="description" >
        <p>{{item.description}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="amount">
        <p>{{item.amount}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add the item description and amount as additional input properties of the budget item card, and then get rid of the `*ngFor` loop in the budget item card.

There is no reason for the individual item component to loop over the parent collection.